# How to use spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc without Entity

Tags: nativequery, spring-data-jdbc

I'm using starter of data-jdbc. It work perfectly, but recently I ran into a problem. I use String class dor returning my generated code. And I didn't see the need to create an entity class for this. I created repository:

```
@Repository 
public interface CodeJDBCRepository { 
    @Query("select api.function(:code, :phone)")
boolean save(
        @Param("code") int code,
        @Param("phone") String phone
);
}
```

But I receive Error

```
Parameter 0 of constructor in com.unistream.service.impl.CodeServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.unistream.repository.CodeJDBCRepository' that could not be found.
```

How to fix it without creating an entity?

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but essentially the same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71177494/is-it-possible-to-use-jparepository-without-entity

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data is build on the repository abstraction which is basically treating all aggregates of a given type as a collection.
All repositories therefore have to specify the aggregate they are handling.

If you don't have an aggregate and just want to execute some SQL query Spring Data JDBC is the wrong tool.
You probably want to switch to Spring JDBC, get a `JdbcTemplate` injected or a `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` and use that.

Comment: Yes, I didn't find answer for my question. So I had to create object for CrudRepository, and use it as usual.
Thanks a lot.